# Can't add Xcode 8 bridging header

Tags: swift, xcode, bridging-header

I am trying to integrate an obj-c library  - specifically Worldpay. I have added the lib and created a bridging header file. However within Xcode 8 I cannot see where to link the reference to it in the build settings. Other answers point to `Objective-C Bridging Header` or `Swift Compiler` but when I search within build settings I do not see it.

I have done this before in previous versions of Xcode.

[image]

Comment: Change the segmented control to All instead of Customized, that way you'll see all options

Comment: Ah thats annoying....

Comment: Customized only show the settings you changed.

Comment: Thanks much appreciated. Worth making it as an answer?

Comment: I'll make one with a screenshot I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the segmented control option. It's customized at the moment, so it will only show the settings you changed yourself. Set it to All.

[image: See all settings]